# Lock screen just for my app

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to have a lock screen just to secure my app . For example if user let s the app in background and enters again lock screen should appear . Same result if the user is in an activity and he does  not do any action for x time .

I used broadcast receiver but it appears all time - if i am not in my app passcode appears .

```
        <receiver
        android:name=".event.broadcast.LockBroadcastRecever"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Is there a method to constraint this BR to handle just my app

Comment: try registering brodcast receiver to your class only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Few days back I implemented a similar feature in my app and hence also created a tip for that which is as follows :**

In this tip , we will talk about the minimum code required to secure unauthorised access to the app once screen has timed out.

Scenario : An app with a pin/password enabled login system. So what if app is left open by mistake and after a small time screen timesout assuming not in user's access anymore. Now what could be the simplest approach to prevent unauthorized access to the app ?

There are two approach to do these whenver screen times out:
1. Implement a pin/password enabled module that provides entry-point to the rest of the modules.
2. Reset the application.

You can define the following two methods in your Utility class.

// Checks if screen has timed out

```
private static boolean isScreenLocked() {
    return !((PowerManager) MainApplication.getsApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).isScreenOn();
}
```

// Checks screenout and defines action to do when screen timed out

```
public static void launchPinActivityWithTimeout(FragmentActivity iActivity) {

    if (isScreenLocked()) {

        //TODO Below code should be the action on screen timed out event. For instance in following code I am launching an activity that contains pin entry form. One could also finish all the activities and restart the app. Similarly many more actions

            Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(iActivity, PinActivationActivity.class);

    //TODO Send any specific information indicating this activity is launched as a result of screen timeout. Here sending boolean indicating device back button must be disabled
            logoutIntent.putExtra("back_should_not_work", true);

    iActivity.startActivity(logoutIntent);
    }
}
```

I called the above method launchPinActivityWithTimeout() in onPause() method of each activity as onPause will always be called for each activity whenever screen timedout.

Please check it if it helps you.